# Add new toc-type showing different section levels

Tags: table-of-contents

All references I found so far on the subject only show how to set the number of levels shown in a table of contents (through `\setcounter{tocdepth}{n}`.

But I would like to define a new (additional) type of toc that lists all sections *below* a given sectioning level.
For example I would like to print a toc at the beginning of each `\part`, listing everything starting with `\chapter`.
(This is especially important if the parts are in subfiles that I also would like to be compilable as standalone documents.

Is there a place (variable, command) where I can define the top level of a toc? Or are there packages for this purpose?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at the [minitoc package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that you haven't accepted answers to your questions. Please consider doing so; I know that you have up-voted answers, but accepting an answer and up-voting are two different actions; in case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) or the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) packages; a third possibility would be to manually create the partial ToCs using `\@starttoc`. Below I show exmples using the packages:

1) Using `titletoc` and its `\startcontents`, `\printcontents` commands. In the example I redefined `\@endpart` (as implemented in `book.cls`) so that the pártial ToCs are automatically generated by each `\part` command; I also made some adjustments so that these partial ToCs will be typeset starting in the same page in which the corresponding sectional heading is shown; additional horizontal rules were also added:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{%
  \vfil
  \hrule
  \startcontents[parts]
  \printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}
  \par\bigskip\hrule
  \vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\part{Test Part Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

And here are some images of the resulting partial ToCs:

[image]

and

[image]

A simple modification to the example allows to place the partial ToCs starting in their own page, and without rules, etc.

2) Now, an example using the `minitoc` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Test Part One}
\parttoc
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\part{Test Part Two}
\parttoc
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

With the standard settings, each partial ToC is now typeset starting in its own page and with a heading, as the images illustrate:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions do what I need. The `minitoc` version seems more straightforward and is probably enough for the actual task at hand. The `titletoc` approach looks somewhat more interesting and configurable, and I'll probably look into that too.